# msbuild error MSB1025 from TFS after adding Wix Projects to VS2010 solution

Tags: tfs, msbuild, wix

We have a number of Windows Service installers we moved to Wix 3.7, our TFS build now breaks with the error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot dispose the build manager because it is not idle.
at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation(String resourceName, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.Dispose()
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Boolean needToValidateProject, String schemaFile, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, Boolean debugger, Boolean detailedSummary)
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String commandLine)
```

This error occurs after all MSI's have been successfully built and copied to the drop folder, indicating that there is nothing wrong with the tasks or target as such, just that the build manager is unable to dispose.  Web searches show [very little information](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696687/msbuild-4-0-30319-17020-crashes-when-running-wix-heat-task).

Which points to build manager reference contention, which is what this appears to be - although applying the workaround environment variable has no effect.

Has anyone else experienced this during a transition from vdproj to WiX in their environment?  Also does anyone have any suggestions for getting any more detail on the error out of TFS/msbuild?

Comment: Have you turned the build logging verbosity to diagnostic?

Comment: Just doing that now Matt, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by Visual studio adding the "Mixed Platforms" configuration into the solution for each Wix project added.  Manually removing it from the solution file post addition appears to fix the issue, msbuild no longer breaks.